# Set height of check list box not working

Tags: c#

I am working in C#, Visual Studio Express 2013.
I have CheckListBox which I can have varying numbers of items in depending upon the underlying data. I'm trying to adjust the height of the CheckListBox dependent upon the number of items.
Currently once the Item list is populate I call the following method to set the height of the CheckListBox:

```c#
        private void SetPanelSize()
        {
            int top = tbInstructions.Height + 2;
            int optionsHeight = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < cbOptions.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                optionsHeight += cbOptions.GetItemHeight(i);
            }

            cbOptions.Location = new Point(4, top);
            cbOptions.Height = optionsHeight;
        }
```

When I run this, the CheckListBox height is set equivalent one item less than the number of items - i.e. if there are three items only two are visible and a scroll down is needed to see the third.
Following it debug, each option height is returned as 16. in the case of three items this gives a optionsHeight of 48.  However when assigned cbOptions.Height is set to 36.

I have seen this in the previous ways that I have calculated height - the value  I calculate is altered when I assign it to the height.
What is going on? Am I missing something?  I cam find no reference to adjustment to the height assignment in the literature I have looked at (MSDN mostly).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CheckListBox itself requires some height. So you need to add optionsHeight to the height of CheckListBox. Try following code and it will work:

```
cbOptions.Height += optionsHeight;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the IntegralHeight property set to false and you have to compensate for the border size, too:

```
cbOptions.IntegralHeight = false;
int optionsHeight = 0;
if (cbOptions.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.Fixed3D) {
  optionsHeight = SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Height * 2;
} else if (cbOptions.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle) {
  optionsHeight = SystemInformation.BorderSize.Height * 2;
}
```